# Retrieving the summary table outputted to terminal when running fviz_silhouette

Tags: r

Is there a way to retrieve the accompanying summary table outputted to the terminal (which includes "cluster", "size" and "average silhouette width") when running fviz_silhouette?
Thanks so much in advance for any input here!

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, if you assign the output of the function to a variable, then you'll find every thing you need in `data`:

```
require(factoextra)
require(cluster)
require(dplyr)

data("iris")
head(iris)
# Remove species column (5) and scale the data
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])

# K-means clustering
# +++++++++++++++++++++
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 2)

# Visualize silhouhette information
sil <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(iris.scaled))
fvis_sil <- fviz_silhouette(sil)
fvis_sil

fvis_sil$data %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  summarise(size = n(), 
            ave.sil.width=round(mean(sil_width), 2))
```